# How to remove Automatic redirection to port 80 by default for ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I've installed a basic ubuntu 18.04,

i'am making some pet project on docker and i map the port 8000 to my 80 docker port

But if i made 127.0.0.1:8000 it automatically redirect me to my ubuntu apache port 80

If in my pet project docker  i put the wordpress not on index but on wordpress/ and type :

127.0.0.1:8000/wordpress/ it works correctly and show the docker wordpress.

But when i type 127.0.0.1:8000 it automatically redirect me to 127.0.0.1 i've try with firefox and chrome.

How to disable this please ?

Regards

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't redirect any ports by default, check your server config

Comment: What if you try the container's IP address instead of your localhost IP ? For example 10.10.10.1:80 .

Comment: You can also use iptables to check whether there's rule that is doing that or not.Run ```sudo iptables -L -n -t nat```

Answer (score 3):

For `apache2`, check the configuration file located at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`.

It's possible that in the first line of that file, the port is specified as `<VirtualHost *:80>`. Changing the port from `80` to your desired port number should give you the result you want.

If you have ever made any other tweaks to the configurations of `apache2` or `localhost`, you may need to review those changes as well.